# Protractor on top of my Selenium Code

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have my code written in Selenium for automating my application[Loading time of it varies] and it works fine when we use Thread.sleep for its loading time.I need to move out of thread.sleep as it is not ideal way of writing code,so i have tried to use all waits[implicit,explicit and fluent] given by Selenium.

In spite of that the script is not consistent and it is failing very often[mostly on element not found and stale element exception],so need to know since i have my all frameworks and code in Selenium is that any provision that i can import protractor jar file in it and use some lines of code in order to make my application to get synchronize with my script.

Comment: Please share what you have tried? It's not possible to use protractor jar in selenium java code

Comment: poor question, what language are you using? Protractor-net is available if you are using c# .net and want to implement protractor functionality... https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net

Answer (score 0):

Your **implicit wait** is not gonna help , if your code works fine with `Thread.sleep()`.

`Thread.sleep(time)` is an extreme case of **Explicit wait**.

An explicit wait is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

In Java selenium binding we can defined and use Explicit wait like this :

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

**Note that** : Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

**Question** : mostly on element not found and stale element exception occurs?

Just verify your locators. Locators should be static not dynamic. Just for example you should never use dynamic ID of any web element which is generated by JS or any other programming language.

Using **protractor**, you can't just sync your script. All you can do now is to make changes to your locator and waiting time.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.` could you give me a link to the source, where I can see that `pooling`?

Comment: @Oleksii : Well , that's what official docs say . here you go (https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i have used all kinds of waits in my script eg: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));getfluentWait;driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(timeout, unit);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, unit);But still the script is failing with waiting time.Also i have used all my static locators to get the elements from the page

Comment: Do not mix every waits. As you have mentioned that with `thread.sleep(time)` your script runs fine , then it should work fine with webDriverWait too.

Comment: But the thing is it is not working fine with my application.

Comment: then share some piece of code and what is not working elaborate about it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use protractor into Selenium, but you can rewrite all tests into protractor and you will inherit all from selenium. Protractor is wrapper for Webdriverjs so you get each and every faeture of webdriverjs in protractor + protractor's own feature of locators and asynchronous waits.